# Increment elements of a subset of elements in a 3d numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, in-place

I have a 3d list formed by

```
myArray = np.array([[[0]*n for i in range(m)] for j in range(o)])
```

I have a loop that runs over all elements, and increments the value stored in the current element and a number of elements in the neighborhood of the current element:

```
myArray[xa:xb][ya:yb][za:zb] += 1.
```

where `xa`,`xb`, etc. are generated according to the current element considered in the loop, and not necessarily the same. In other words, I'd like to increment the values of a given sub-triangle in the 3D list.

However, when I try to address `myArray[xa:xb][0][0]`, I get a list with length that is larger than `len(myArray[0])`. Not to mention `myArray[xa:xb][ya:yb][za:zb] += 1` results in more elements to be incremented by `1` than desired.

I could achieve this by using three nested for loops:

```
for i in range(xa,xb+1):
    for j in range(ya,yb+1):
        for k in range(za,zb+1):
            myArray[i][j][k] += 1
```

but this slows down the code a lot. 
What can I do to achieve this without such a loss of performance?

Comment: Tip - you can write the first line as `myArray = np.zeros((o, m, n))` and check the dimensions of an array or a slice with `myArray.shape` or `myarray[xa:xb][0].shape`, etc. It might be that the dimensions of `myArray` are not in the order you expect. Also I would not recommend using `o` as a variable name...

Comment: @YXD thanks. I think the problem lies in the fact that `myArray[xa:xb][0]` is still a 2D array, equivalent to `myArray[xa]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right path from the beginning. The following seems to work:

```
myArray=np.zeros((o,m,n))
myArray[xa:xb+1,ya:yb+1,za:zb+1]+=1
```

Note that index slicing in arrays uses the same boundaries as `range` in your `for` loop, thus you have to `+1` your end index. The procedure above replicates your triple `for` loops results, at a fraction of time.